# Relaciones con laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Estoy haciendo un desarrollo con laravel y me surge la duda en cuanto a las relacione y obtención de datos. En un principio tengo dos tablas USUARIOS y EMPRESAS donde el usuario puede tener una o varias empresas. hasta ahi todo ok, los problemas surgen cuando entra en juego una tercera tabla llamada EMPLEADOS , ya que esta me deriva de otra relación M:M de las dos tablas anteriores, en la que muchos usuarios pueden ser empleados.

Ademas de las claves primarias esta tabla tendrá datos adicionales unicamente concernientes al empleado.  Así que son tres tablas las que quedan.

Para la primera relación de los modelos USUARIO Y EMPRESA , tengo estas relaciones:

En User.php

```
public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Company');
    }
```

En Empresa.php

```
public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

Esta relación me funciona sin problemas; el problema nace cuando intento relacionarlos  la tabla empleados he visto tutoriales pero la verdad no se realmente como me debería quedar establecida ya que he usado lo que muestran los tutos y no lo consigo.

También he utilizado belongToMany y no lo he podido hacer funcionar y la verdad me he liado mucho.

no me sale ningún error por pantalla simplemente es que no trae ningún dato de la tabla empleados.

Gracias

Comment: Vas a manejar los empleados de múltiples empresas o solo de una?

Comment: Sera manejado asi: el administrador de todo el sistema tiene acceso global y cada propietario de empresa vera solo los empleados de su empresa, si tiene  dos empresas al acceder a una de ellas vería solo los de esa empresa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que deberías considerar tener una estructura de tablas como la siguiente:

> Pues la entidad usuario no tiene por qué representar o a los dueños o a los empleados, además de eso necesitas una tabla que represente que roles van a ser manejados

**Escenario a nivel de SQL**

```
Duenios
id
nombreDuenio
.........

Roles
id
nombreRol
........


Usuarios
id
......
......
duenio_id
rol_id


Empresas
id
nombreEmpresa
direccion
duenio_id
etc......

Empleados
id
nombreEmpleado
........
empresa_id
```

Razones:

- Cuando des de alta a un dueño de empresa, solo debe tener datos que sean relevantes a el mismo
- En otra tabla registrarás los roles de usuario, considerando que nos dices que:

  - El administrador tiene acceso global
  - El dueño solo puede ver su empresa o empresas (si es que tiene mas)
- Cuando le vayas a crear un usuario a un dueño de empresa, entonces registrarás las llaves foráneas de la tabla: **`dueños`** y de la tabla **`roles`**
- Cuando des de alta a un empresa, solo vas a registrar la llaves foránea del dueño al cual le pertenece, (considerando esto, entonces puedes tener el escenario de **`1:N`**) donde un dueño tiene una o muchas empresas
- Cuando des de alta a un empleado lo asocias a una empresa, registrando en la tabla de empleado el id o llave foránea de la tabla empresa, (de tal modo que tengas una relación **`1:N`**) **una empresa tiene 1 o varios empleados y un empleado pertenece a una empresa**

**Escenario a nivel de Eloquent y sus relaciones**

El modelo **`Duenio`** solo deberá tener una relación del tipo **`hasMany`** para relacionarlo con el modelo **`Empresa`**

Modelo Duenio

```
public function empresas()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Empresa::class);
}
```

- El modelo **`Rol`** deberá tener una relación del tipo **`belongsTo`** con el modelo **`User`** para indicar que un rol pertenece a un usuario
- El modelo **`User`** por el contrario debería tener una relación del tipo **`hasOne`** para indicar que un usuario solo puede tener un perfil, **(esto en razón que comentas que los dueños solo pueden ver a sus empresas mientras que el admin puede ver todo)**

Modelo Rol

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Modelo User

```
public function rol()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Rol::class);
}
```

Por otro lado el modelo **`Empresa`** debe tener una relación del tipo **`belongsTo`** con el modelo **`Duenio`** para indicar que pertenece a un dueño, además debe tener una relación **`hasMany`** con el modelo **`Empleado`** del tipo **`hasMany`** para identificar que una empresa puede tener uno o varios empleados

Modelo Empresa

```
public function duenio()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Duenio::class);
}

public function empleados()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Empleado::class);
}
```

Finalmente en el modelo **`Empleado`** debe existir una relación del tipo **`belongsTo`** con el modelo **`Empresa`** para indentificar que un empleado pertenece a una empresa

Modelo Empleado

```
public function empresa()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Empresa::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que te falta especificar tablas `pivot` e `id` mediante las cuales se relacionaran, y no necesaria y unicamente de tablas, pueden haber mas relaciones mediante la tabla `pivot` `empresa_user` que naturalmente deberia tener `[iduser,idempresa]` entre sus atributos

y en tu consulta `$usuario->empresa` te devuelve un `array` y tambien `$empresa->usuario`

En caso de que salga un error de no encontrar `id` juega intercambiando el orden de los parámetros.

**Usuario**

```
function empresa(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Empresa', 'empresa_user', 'empresa_id', 'user_id');
}
```

**Empresa**

```
function usuario(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'empresa_user', 'user_id', 'empresa_id');
}
```

Comment: Hola chicos  gracias por su tiempo. Si la estructura que tengo es muy similar a la que me propones y creo que ya estoy solucionando el problema debo terminar de ajustar algunas cosas. En breve creo que lo tendría ya te comentare mas cosas.

Comment: Por favor considera que si está respuesta solucionó tu problema sería bueno la marqués como aceptada @Adrian

Comment: @Apreniz muchas gracias , ahora mismo la marco.